# Filter columns by group and condition

Tags: r, bash, awk

I have a kind of easy task but still can't figure it out.
I have a csv binary matrix, with genes as rows and samples as columns,  where 1 means that the gene is present, 0 when the gene is absent.
Samples belong to different clusters, like:
cluster1 = c(sampleA, sampleB, sampleC, sampleD)
cluster2 = c(sampleE, sampleF, sampleG)
Here as ideal example:

| Gene | sampleA | sampleB | sampleC | sampleD | sampleE | sampleF | sampleG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| gene3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| gene4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| gene8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene9 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene11 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| gene13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| gene14 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene16 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene17 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene19 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene20 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I need to find out which genes are present only in one cluster and absent in all the other clusters. Which means, I would like to subset/filter the columns according to the gene presence in only one cluster, like this:

Cluster1:

| sampleA | sampleB | sampleC | sampleD | sampleE | sampleF | sampleG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| gene6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Cluster2:

| sampleA | sampleB | sampleC | sampleD | sampleE | sampleF | sampleG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| gene13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

My original dataset contains 8212 genes and 23 samples, organized in 8 different clusters:

```
cluster1 <- c("sampleA", "sampleB", "sampleC", "sampleD", "sampleE", "sampleF", "sampleG", "sampleH", 
              "sampleI", "sampleJ", "sampleK", "sampleL", "sampleM", "sampleN", "sampleO") 
cluster2 <- c("sampleP")
cluster3 <- c("sampleQ", "sampleR")
cluster4 <- c("sampleS")
cluster5 <- c("sampleT")
cluster6 <- c("sampleU")
cluster7 <- c("sampleV")
cluster8 <- c("sampleZ")
```

[Here is an example file](https://easyupload.io/5kj3h6)

Is there any easy way with R or bash?
Thanks

Comment: not everyone who sees this question is going to know what 'gene presence' or 'pecularity' means; for many of us this is just a file with a bunch of text so consider updating the question with a more general description of what we're looking for in the inputs; also, are these 'clusters' know beforehand or do they need to be fed to the program as additional inputs?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I changed the question and hope that it is more clear now..

Comment: how do you go from an input of `gene6 1 0 0 1 1 0 0` to an output of `gene6 1 1 1 1 0 0 0`

Comment: That was just a typing mistake while creating the table, sorry.

Comment: sorry, still clear as mud .... ***guessing*** .... a `1` indicates a gene is present in a sample? and you want to output the rows where a gene is present (ie, `1`) in all samples of a given cluster? but only if the gene is present in exactly one cluster (ie, ignore lines where the gene is present in all samples of multiple clusters)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to know which genes are present ONLY in one cluster and absent in the other clusters.

Comment: [edit] your question to replace the graphical tables with raw text that we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: [edit] your question to explain why `gene8` (and others) are missing from the expected output as it satisfies your stated requirement of being `present only in one cluster and absent in all the other clusters`. Maybe you need to add something about it needing to be present in all samples for the cluster it's in?

Comment: your example clusters appear to suggest that a sample can only belong to a single cluster ... is this correct? or can a sample belong to more than one cluster (and if so could you update the question with an example)?

Comment: a sample can only belong to a single cluster, absolutely yes.

Answer (score 1):

update 4/13/23:

```
clusterno=paste0("cluster",1:8)

getmatch <- function(cluster){
  pangenome[rowSums(pangenome[,get0(cluster),drop=F])==length(get0(cluster)) &
            rowSums(pangenome[,!names(pangenome) %in% c(get0(cluster),"Gene")])==0
            ,]
}

do.call(rbind,lapply(clusterno,getmatch))  #output has 280 rows
```

This should preserve all of the other additional columns

```
cluster1 = c("sampleA", "sampleB", "sampleC", "sampleD")
cluster2 = c("sampleE", "sampleF", "sampleG")

rbind(df[rowSums(df[,cluster1])==length(cluster1),],
      df[rowSums(df[,cluster2])==length(cluster2),])

     Gene sampleA sampleB sampleC sampleD sampleE sampleF sampleG
5   gene5       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
6   gene6       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
12 gene12       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
13 gene13       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
```

Generalized:

-apply

```
clusterno <- c("cluster1","cluster2")
getmatch <- function(cluster){
  df[rowSums(df[,get0(cluster)])==length(get0(cluster)),]
}

do.call(rbind,lapply(clusterno,getmatch))

     Gene sampleA sampleB sampleC sampleD sampleE sampleF sampleG
5   gene5       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
6   gene6       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
12 gene12       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
13 gene13       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
```

-for loop

```
clusterno <- c("cluster1","cluster2")
out <- data.frame()
for(cluster in clusterno){
  temp_df <- df[rowSums(df[,get0(cluster)])==length(get0(cluster)),]
  out <- rbind(out,temp_df)
}

out
     Gene sampleA sampleB sampleC sampleD sampleE sampleF sampleG
5   gene5       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
6   gene6       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
12 gene12       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
13 gene13       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Does this work also with much more clusters or genes? Like this it seems that it's matter of equal length, but with the real complete dataset may not be the case..

Comment: Yes, the answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks Peter. When I try this code to my complete dataset (pangenome), both apply or for loop example, I get the same error: Error in rowSums(pangenome[, get0(cluster)]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: could you try ```rowSums(pangenome[,get0(cluster), drop = FALSE])```?

Comment: In this way: pangenome[rowSums(pangenome[,get0(cluster), drop = FALSE])==length(get0(cluster)),]   or this way: pangenome[rowSums(pangenome[,get0(cluster), drop = FALSE])==length(get0(cluster)),]   it works but the output is not correct. It gives me a df with all 1 for all the samples and all the genes.

Comment: Could you give a more representative dataset that mimic pangenome dataset?

Comment: Peter, https://easyupload.io/5kj3h6 here the complete dataset as example. Please look at the first post for the clusters. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the dataset. The answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks. But My output has 0 rows: do.call(rbind,lapply(clusterno,getmatch))
 [1] sampleA sampleB sampleC sampleD sampleE sampleF sampleG sampleH sampleI sampleJ sampleK sampleL
[13] sampleM sampleN sampleO sampleP sampleQ sampleR sampleS sampleT sampleU sampleV sampleZ
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>

Answer (score 0):

First create two variables to hold the columns names:

```
set1<- c('sampleA','sampleB','sampleC','sampleD')

set2<- c('sampleE','sampleF','sampleG')

df %>% filter(xor(rowSums(.[set1])==length(set1),rowSums(.[set2])==length(set2)))
```

I am using the combination of base R and Dyplr functions.
xor returns true if one condition is true and other false. If both conditions are true or false then it return false.

Comment: Thanks Sajil. But I am afraid that this cannot be applied to a large dataset where you don't know the columns notation in advance..

Comment: I have changed the code to make it dynamic.

Comment: Hi Sajil, I tried with my original dataset and as above, the output is completely random and not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the clusters after hierarchical clustering, 5 and 7 in this case.

```
library(dplyr) # for "filter" and "select"

cbind(df, clust = cutree(hclust(dist(df[,-1])), h=0)) %>% 
  filter(clust %in% c(5,7)) %>% 
  select(-clust)
    Gene sampleA sampleB sampleC sampleD sampleE sampleF sampleG
1  gene5       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
2  gene6       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
3 gene11       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
4 gene12       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
```

Visual help to choose the desired cluster number

```
rownames(df) <- paste(apply(df[,-1], 1, paste0, collapse=""), 1:nrow(df))

ctree <- cutree(hclust(dist(df[,-1])), h=0)

ctree[!duplicated(sub(" .*", "", names(ctree)))]
 1001000 1  0000110 2  0000001 3  0100000 4  1111000 5  0000000 8 0000111 10 
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
0000010 13 1000000 14 
         8          9
```

Comment: Hi Andre, why 5 and 7?

Comment: @Silvia These are the numbers of the desired clusters. Choosing `h=0` will give you a distinct number for each unique cluster, grouping all existing expression patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Update (removed prior solution):
Here is a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

cluster1 <- c("sampleA", "sampleB", "sampleC", "sampleD")
cluster2 <- c("sampleE", "sampleF", "sampleG")

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(all_of(cluster1), ~ . == 1)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              filter(if_all(all_of(cluster2), ~. == 1))) 

  sampleA sampleB sampleC sampleD sampleE sampleF sampleG
1       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
2       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
3       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
4       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
```

Comment: Thanks TarJae. However I got this error: Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @Silvia use `dplyr::select`. I am sure that select interferes with other packages (like MASS) for example!

Comment: It is working now but the output, in my complete dataset, is not correct. I have 8212 rows (genes) and 23 samples. It just take the first 3000 more or less as belonging to cluster 1 and the rest as belonging to cluster2. But it's not true ^^

Comment: As before (and as for Peter's suggestions) the output is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = ","
        clusters[1] = "sampleA,sampleB,sampleC,sampleD"
        clusters[2] = "sampleE,sampleF,sampleG"
    }
    NR == 1 {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            tag2val[$i] = i
        }
        print
        next
    }
    {
        numClustersFull = numClustersPartial = 0
        for ( i in clusters ) {
            numSamplesPresent = 0
            totSamples = split(clusters[i],samples)
            for ( j in samples ) {
                numSamplesPresent += $(tag2val[samples[j]])
            }
            if ( numSamplesPresent == totSamples ) {
                numClustersFull++
            }
            else if ( numSamplesPresent != 0 ) {
                numClustersPartial++
            }
        }
    }
    (numClustersFull == 1) && (numClustersPartial == 0)
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
Gene,sampleA,sampleB,sampleC,sampleD,sampleE,sampleF,sampleG
gene5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
gene6,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
gene11,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
gene12,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
```

The above was run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
Gene,sampleA,sampleB,sampleC,sampleD,sampleE,sampleF,sampleG
gene1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
gene2,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
gene3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
gene4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
gene5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
gene6,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
gene8,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
gene9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
gene10,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
gene11,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
gene12,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
gene13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
gene14,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
gene16,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
gene17,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
gene18,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
gene19,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
gene20,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

Comment: Ed! That is perfect :)) May I just ask you how can I save the output in separated file according to the clusters? Like clusters1.txt, cluster2.txt .. Thanks!!

Comment: @Silvia [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged in this forum, please just ask a new question about that new topic if you can't figure that out for yourself.